# How to get pass this error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity"

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var rec = dc.reportsSents.FirstOrDefault();
        int rowCount = dc.reportsSents.Count();


        if (rec != null)
            {

            for(int i = 0; i <= rowCount;)
                {


                    var matchedCaseNumber = (from CaseNumberKey in dc.GetTable<reportsSent>()
                                     select CaseNumberKey).FirstOrDefault();

                    (new MyReportRenderer()).RenderTest(Convert.ToString(matchedCaseNumber));

                    dc.reportsSents.DeleteOnSubmit(matchedCaseNumber);
                    dc.SubmitChanges();

                    i = (i +1);

                } 

             }
```

When the code above is executed I get this error:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   entity

and matchedCaseNumber is highlighted in this line:

dc.reportsSents.DeleteOnSubmit(matchedCaseNumber);

What does this mean and why am I getting it.  What I am trying to do is pass MatchedCaseNumber to the method and then delete it after the method is executed and then step through the table.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matchedCaseNumber` is probably `null` when passed to `DeleteOnSubmit`

```
if(matchedCaseNumber != null)
{
  dc.reportsSents.DeleteOnSubmit(matchedCaseNumber);
  dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

**EDIT:**
If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, this would be better:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    foreach (var item in dc.reportsSents)
    {
        (new MyReportRenderer()).RenderTest(Convert.ToString(item));
        dc.reportsSents.DeleteOnSubmit(item);
    }
    dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: I have it in the loop because every time it loops through it needs to pull the next record as the prior one was deleted.  Is there a better way to do that???

Comment: @korrowan A reportsSent item in the table

Answer (score 6):

You have

```
var matchedCaseNumber = (...).FirstOrDefault();

dc.reportsSents.DeleteOnSubmit(matchedCaseNumber);
```

So what if `matchedCaseNumber` is null?  The `OrDefault` makes that possible.

Change that 2nd line into:

```
if (matchedCaseNumber != null)
    dc.reportsSents.DeleteOnSubmit(matchedCaseNumber);
```

Also,

```
int rowCount = dc.reportsSents.Count();

for(int i = 0; i <= rowCount;)
{
   ...
   i = (i +1);    
}
```

should probably become:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i += 1)  // note: NOT <=
{
    ...    
}
```

You are looping rowCount+1 times. And there really is no point in moving the increment of `i` out of the loop statement. Don't confuse/hinder opitimizers.

Comment: if it is null then that is a problem as this should only execute when there is a record in the table..if there is no record than it should not.. I must have made a mistake in the code prior to this line.

Comment: @korrowan, when you _expect_ 1+ items returned, don't use `.FirstOrDefault()`. Also see Edit.

Answer (score 1):

It means that `matchCaseNumber` is `null`.

When you create matchCaseNumber you use `.FirstOrDefault()` which returns the first instance or the default value for that type (which is `null` for reference types).

In other words, your query:

```
from CaseNumberKey in dc.GetTable<reportsSent>()
select CaseNumberKey
```

appears to be returning no data.